# Reactive form typing in Angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, types

Could you help me by giving me an example applying a data model to the reactive form with formBuilder?
I have done it with formGroup and it worked, but I have not been able to do the same with formBuilder.

This is my function that tries to return the formGroup via formBuilder.

```
public brandingFormControl() {
    return this._fb.group<FormBrand>({
        brand: ['', {validators: [Validators.required], nonNullable: true}],
        body_font: ['', {validators: [Validators.required], nonNullable: true}],
        body_color_font: ['', {validators: [Validators.required], nonNullable: true}],
    })
};
```

My interface:

```
interface FormBrand {
    brand: FormControl<string>;
    body_font: FormControl<string>;
    body_color_font: FormControl<string>;
}
```

And the error I get is this.

```
TS2740: Type
(string | {     
    validators: ((control: AbstractControl<any, any>) => ValidationErrors | null)[];
    nonNullable: true;
})[] 
is missing the following properties from type FormControl<string> :  defaultValue, setValue, patchValue, reset , and  56  more.
form-workflow.service.ts(127, 5): The expected type comes from property  brand  which is declared here on type  FormBrand
```

[image]

I hope you can help me with an example of how to insert a data type to a reactive form with formBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

`FormBrand` expects a group with `FormControl`, so try specifying each control:

```
public brandingFormControl() {
    return this._fb.group<FormBrand>({
        brand: this._fb.control('', {validators: [Validators.required], nonNullable: true}),
        body_font: this._fb.control('', {validators: [Validators.required], nonNullable: true}),
        body_color_font: this._fb.control('', {validators: [Validators.required], nonNullable: true}),
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your interface like this:

```html
interface FormBrand {
    brand: string;
    body_font: string;
    body_color_font: string;
}
```

=> In the FormBrand interface, we specify the types as plain strings, not as FormControl. This interface defines the expected structure of your form data.

=> When creating the FormGroup using the FormBuilder, we use the FormBrand interface as the type parameter to ensure type safety and to match the structure defined in the interface.

And modify your method like this:

```html
public brandingFormControl() {
    return this._fb.group<FormBrand>({
        brand: ['', [Validators.required]],
        body_font: ['', [Validators.required]],
        body_color_font: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
}
```

=> We specify the validation using an array with [Validators.required] for each form control.

It will work!